# Select data from XML with namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am newbie to SQL and XML. My aim is to get the data from all the elements within the **Client** block but the SELECT not returning any data. Without the namespace the query works.

Can you help?

```
DECLARE @x XML='<BusinessEvent Name="FO.Client">
            <ClientMessage xmlns="http://www.fwbs.net/Aderant.BO.Integration/FO.MessageTypes.xsd"> 
                <OriginatingProcessIdentity></OriginatingProcessIdentity>
                <Operation></Operation>
                <IsDataIncluded></IsDataIncluded>
                <Clients>
                    <Client>
                        <GlobalId></GlobalId>
                        <ClID>g</ClID>
                        <No></No>
                        <Type></Type>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <BrCode></BrCode>
                        <Created></Created>
                        <FeeUsrID></FeeUsrID>
                        <DefaultAddID></DefaultAddID>
                        <ContID></ContID>
                    </Client>
                </Clients>
            </ClientMessage>
        </BusinessEvent>'


     ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES
         (DEFAULT 'http://www.fwbs.net/Aderant.BO.Integration/FO.MessageTypes.xsd')         
        SELECT TOP 10 cl.c.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') clid
    FROM (SELECT @x data) data
    CROSS APPLY [data].nodes('/BusinessEvent/ClientMessage/Clients/Client/ClID') AS cl(c)
```

Comment: The answer @marc_s gave you helps you with the namespace (Although your solution with `DEFAULT` was OK, if you changed nothing but `....nodes('/*:BusinessEvent...`, to wildcard the namespace of the outer-most node.) Just one hint: As you want to *get the data from all the elements within the Client block*, you should stop the `XPath` in `.nodes()` after client to read each element with `c.value('ClID[1]','nvarchar(max)')`. This allows you to address all inner elements with the same `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the namespace is *not* on the root element, and thus does *not* apply to the *whole* XML document, you cannot define it as a "default" namespace in your T-SQL code - you need to be specific:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.fwbs.net/Aderant.BO.Integration/FO.MessageTypes.xsd' AS ns)         
SELECT TOP 10 
    cl.c.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') clid
FROM 
    @x.nodes('/BusinessEvent/ns:ClientMessage/ns:Clients/ns:Client/ns:ClID') AS cl(c)
```

The `<BusinessEvent>` element is **not** part of that XML namespace - but if you define it as the `DEFAULT` namespace in your T-SQL statement, that default namespace will be applied to **all** of your XML elements as defined in your XPath - so the `<BusinessEvent>` top level node is *NOT* matched....

Comment: Good catch with the namespace, +1 from my side. I think, the `XPath` should not go down to `ns:ClID`, but stop after `ns:Client` to get hands on the inner elements in one go (see my comment to OP).